# Convert a user inputted string to a class that gets cast

Tags: c#, string, gettype

I have a string that gets inputted by a user. The string can look like: Button.Minimize or Hyperlink.SomeLink

I need to take the first part of the string and convert it to a class that is located in a dll library. Then I need to cast that as a type.

I have seen countless examples on here but none that show how to convert the string to ANY type. All the examples I have seen are when you know which type you want to convert the string to beforehand.

Basically I need a method that converts a string to any kind of class name. Like: Button, HyperLink, etc...

```
    public static void ClickOn(Step step)
    {
        string[] kvp = step.Element.Split('.');

        var type = kvp[0];
        var element = kvp[1];

        GetType(type);

        var path = MainWin.Get<type>(element); //inputted string would be cast in this line where you see <type>

        path.Click();
    }

    public static Type GetType(string typeName)
    {
        Type get = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
        Object type = (Activator.CreateInstance(get));

        return type;
    }
```

Comment: If the types you are dynamically creating don't share an interface or abstract class, how are you gonna treat them? let's say you receive Button and manage to have this: Button b = ...; what are you gonna do with b? if you return it from the method, the handler will not be of type Button.

Comment: I guess I wasn't being clear. In my code where I have: var path = MainWin.Get<type> <<that is where I'm casting the class name/type. Maybe I'm not using the correct terminology here. Basically <type> should be the inputted string.

Comment: Yes, I understand but your method GetType doesn't compile because you are declaring that you are gonna return a Type object and you are returning a Object object. Activator.CreateInstance is creating an object of the type you specified. GetTypeMethod should return Object but the problem is what I described in my first comment, what are you gonna do with an object of type Object? your handler path is gonna be of type Object, you don't have a Click method.

Comment: Read my answer and let me know if that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean cast as in `(string)anObject` then there is no way to do this.  Casting in this way is a compile time activity that gives the compiler awareness about the type that it is working with.  Since what you are describing is essentially a runtime activity, there is nothing that the compiler can do to help you at this point.

If you write a different question that describes the problem you are trying to solve with this in more detail (or change this question), then someone can probably suggest a way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: In my code where I have: var path = MainWin.Get<type> <<that is where I'm casting the class name/type. Maybe I'm not using the correct terminology here. Basically <type> should be the inputted string.

Answer (score 0):

Define interface called IClickablewith a Click method and make all the classes implement that interface. Rename your method GetType to GetClickableObject and make that method return a IClickable. Something like this:

```
public static void ClickOn(Step step)
    {
        // get type
        string fullClassType = ...;    
        IClickable obj = MainWin.GetClickableObject(fullClassType);

        obj.Click();
    }

    public static IClickable GetClickableObject(string typeName)
    {
        Type get = Type.GetType(typeName, true);
        IClickable obj = (IClickable)Activator.CreateInstance(get);

        return obj;
    }
}

interface IClickable 
{
       void Click();
}

class Button : IClickable 
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I know right off the bat that this will not work for my particular problem. I'm using a library called TestStack.White to setup a framework that will automate desktop applications. While I think your answer is suffice, it's just not going to cut it. The library's classes will not work with your answer. 

Thank you for the help anyways.

Comment: Have you consider adding extension methods to the classes (if they cannot implement an interface) and invoke those methods using reflection?